# if else is not working in transaction method

Tags: transactions, ruby-on-rails-5

I have tried this code for below condition

```
school.school_code != params[:school_code]
```

when I am tring this code I am getting the same answer.it is updating the teacher_code, student_code and school_code for both conditions whether it is true or false which means the if - else is not working.
partials_controller.rb

```
class PartialsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def update_school_and_teacher_code
    school = School.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if school.school_code != params[:school_code]
      School.transaction do 
        school.update_attributes!(:school_code => params[:school_code])        
        teacher = Teacher.find(params[:teacher_id])
        teacher.update_attributes!(:teacher_code => school.school_code)
        student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
        student.update_attributes!(:student_code => school.school_code) 
        render json: { message: ' data updated '}
      end
    else
      render json: { message: ' data not updated '}
    end
    rescue => e
      render json: { error: ' data not found '}
  end
end
```

everything is write in this Code but the if-else is not working so when the condition true or false for both it gives 
**message: data updated**

Comment: If you print `school.school_code` and `params[:school_code]`, what do you get?

Comment: when I type params[:school_code] according to if condition it provides the params of school code. school.school_code is school_code of this school = School.find_by_id(params[:id])

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output for both?

Comment: when I pass these parameters Parameters: {"id"=>"5", "school_code"=>"2", "teacher_id"=>"2", "student_id"=>"2"} which true the if statement because the school having id 5 school_code is 3 so it is not equal to provided school_code 2 so it should update and it gives message "data updated"

Comment: my question is my if else condition is not working it Is updating what  want to do but not according to if else condition